# Clear session on browser exit for php

Tags: php, session

I am working on a PHP project where I need to clear the session on click browser close.

My project :

Index.php -> userdata.php -> reports.php ->finalreport.html

is it possible to handle session destroy?

I need to clear session, whenever user exits browser while they are in any page.

Please let me know how can we handle this.

Comment: Browsers do already discard [session cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) when the browser session ends; that doesn’t suffice, or does it?

Comment: Is it about browser session, or the "server-session" (content of $_SESSION)

Answer (score 5):

the session is destroyed when the user closes the browser**. if you want to destroy it as soon as the user unloads the page, you could add a handler to the page unload event (something like [jquery unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)) and do a ajax request to a script that just clears the session.

EDIT: per OP's request, i'll add specific code.

1) in all pages (Index.php, userdata.php, reports.php, finalreport.html) add this javascript code

```
 $(window).unload(function() {
   $.get('session_destroyer.php');
 });
```

2) in session_destroyer.php use this code (taken from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php))

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

hope this helps

** NOTE:  as one commenter noted, this assumes you're using cookie-based sessions (which is the default in PHP, i think)

Comment: You’re wrong. The browser does only discard the session’s cookie (if it’s actually a [session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie)). The actual session is still alive.

Comment: but I want to delete the temp files that were created while the session destroyed

Comment: check out the first example on this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: I understood the example but the problem is when to call this delete session cookies ? and in which file

Comment: @vineel: PHP takes care of deleting the outdated session files after some time automatically. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime